# IntegrityError using q.save(): may not be NULL

Tags: django

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Here are the views and clesses

```
from polls.models import Word, Results

def detail(request):
    q = Word(type="How do you like")
    q.save()
    Word.objects.get(pk=1)

    q.score_set.create(score=5)
    q.score_set.create(score=4)
    q.score_set.create(score=3)
    q.score_set.create(score=2)
    q.score_set.create(score=1)


    return render_to_response('/$')
```

Models.py

```
 from django.db import models


class Word(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.type

class Results(models.Model):
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    score = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.score
```

Error:

```
IntegrityError at /
polls_word.score may not be NULLRequest Method: GET 
Request URL: Django Version: 1.4.1 
Exception Type: IntegrityError 
Exception Value: polls_word.score may not be NULL 
Exception Location: /home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 337 
Python Executable: /home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/bin/python 
Python Version: 2.6.6 
Python Path: ['/home/oveledar/django/mysite',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib64/python2.6',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/home/oveledar/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. With the models you have here, `Word` doesn't have a `score_set` - it has `results_set`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by actual code. I have the models, views, urls, and templates. I'm not utilizing urls and templates yet so I just posted models and views.

Comment: The point is that this code would give a different error to the one you have shown - it would give an `AttributeError` for `score_set`.

Comment: The error I posted is from this code. I just ran it again. What rest of the code would you be talking about?

Comment: Just curious, why are you doing this query in line 6 of your code?

Comment: I'm just trying to modify the tutorial to create a question with 5 different choices. The tutorial creates the question in the python shell but I figured I could do it in a view.

Answer (score 1):

You table structure incorrect, you need:

```
class Results(models.Model):
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

after, remove this table and run command:

```
python manange.py syncdb
```

#`blank` option it`s required or not this node for form validate

#`null` option it`s for you database (Null true or false)

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same problem.